# Which web-technology could I use to highlight parts of an object, and spin it 360 degrees (in one direction)?

Tags: database, web, rotation

The website will grab data from a database telling it which part to highlight, on any of 4 models.

Please tell me which web-technology would be best for this.

Thanks,

Alec Taylor

Comment: No, my object could be a human-body (muscular), a human-body (skeletal) or even a car!

Comment: Intresting. Should those pages be indexed by a search engine?

Comment: None of the image content needs to be indexed, only the database search results (shown in the right sidebar of the site)

Comment: You need to [edit] this and improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can point you toward those two open source choices:

- [**Adobe Flex**](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) (Needs Flash Player and JavaScript enabled on client)
- **HTML5 Canvas** [Link1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) [Link2](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/) (Needs HTML5 support on client's browser)

You can also have a look at [**Microsoft Silverlight**](http://www.silverlight.net/showcase/) but it relies too much upon MS Technology

Comment: I'd like to avoid Flash, HTML5 isn't a bad solution.

Comment: You can also have a look at this comparison http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/39/adobe-air-vs-flash-vs-flex-vs-microsoft-silverlight/